# Separating fileInput from radioButtons into shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

When running the code below, you will notice that I have two options below. If you press the `Excel` option, a `fileInput` will appear right below the `radioButtons`. However, I would like to know if it is possible to separate `fileInput` from `radioButtons`. I will insert an image to clarify what I want. See that they are separated.

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(readxl)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("PAGE1",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 radioButtons("button", 
                                              label = h3("Data source"),
                                              choices = list("Excel" = "Excel",
                                                             "Database" = "database"), 
                                              selected = "File"),
                                 uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 
                               )))))



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observe({
    if(is.null(input$button)) {
      
    }else if (input$button =="Excel"){

      output$fileInput <- renderUI({
        fileInput("file",h4("Import file"), multiple = T, accept = ".xlsx")
      })
      
    } else if(input$button=="database"){
      
      output$fileInput <- NULL

      
    } else {
      output$fileInput <- NULL
    }
    
  
  })
  
  
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Example:**
[image]

I left it in red to specify the space
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be to use `fluidRow` with two columns to simulating a sidebarPanel with a mainPanel.

Notice that I wrapped the inputs in a div(class = "well well-lg") for the background.

App

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(readxl)


ui <- navbarPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
  br(),
  tabPanel(
    "PAGE1",
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        fluidRow(div(
          class = "well well-lg",
          radioButtons("button",
            label = h3("Data source"),
            choices = list(
              "Excel" = "Excel",
              "Database" = "database"
            ),
            selected = "File"
          )
        )),
        fluidRow(
          uiOutput("fileInput")
        )
      ),
      column(
        width = 6,
        tableOutput("iris")
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$iris <- renderTable({
    iris
  })

  observe({
    if (is.null(input$button)) {

    } else if (input$button == "Excel") {
        
      output$fileInput <- renderUI({
        div(class = "well well-lg", fileInput("file", h4("Import file"), multiple = T, accept = ".xlsx"))
      })
    } else if (input$button == "database") {
      output$fileInput <- NULL
    } else {
      output$fileInput <- NULL
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jpdugo17, but I found it a bit strange to have a space when running the app. I inserted the image in the question for you to see. I think it would have to appear only when `fileInput` appears, isn't it?

Comment: @Antonio Yes, i believe now its fixed.  Now it should appear after de UI is rendered. Check the edit.